# Implications of pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference in C#

Tags: c#, oop, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I was following along a tutorial online about C#. The tutorial talks about passing-by-reference vs passing-by-value. What I am confused about specifically is that since in C#, there is a distinction between reference types vs value types, how does that distinction affect the output of the following two functions.

In the following code snippet:

```
  public void CanSetNameFromReference()
    {
        Book book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
        SetName(book1, "New Name");
        Assert.Equal("New Name", book1.Name);

    }

    private void SetName(Book book, string name)
    {
        book.Name = name;
    }
```

We pass in an object of type Book into SetName and we see that SetName correctly sets the name of book1 to "New Name", even though book is being passed by reference.

On the other hand in the code snippet below, this does not seem to be the case:

```
   public void CSharpIsPassByValue()
    {
        var book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
        GetBookSetName(book1, "New Name");

        Assert.Equal("Book 1", book1.Name);
    }

    private void GetBookSetName(Book book, string name)
    {
        book = new Book(name);
    }
```

Why is this the case?

Finally, in the code snippet below,

```
  public void CSharpCanPassByReference()
    {
        var book1 = GetBook("Book 1");
        GetBookSetName(ref book1, "New Name");
        
        Assert.Equal("New Name", book1.Name);
    }

    private void GetBookSetName(ref Book book, string name)
    {
        book = new Book(name);
    }
```

we are passing in by reference. In this case, what is happening? How is this different from the first case?

Comment: @KenWhite I understand the distinction that the post makes between passing-by-value and passing-by-reference. But what I don't understand is that how is this logic being used in the examples above? It seems that both the first and the second functions do the same thing, yet the result is different.

Comment: @KenWhite Additionally, the how pass-by-reference and pass-by-value behaves depends on what is being passed in. Because what I am passing in is in C# a reference type (and not a value type), I assume my question has more granularity than the one you pasted above which does not take into account value types vs reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused "pass by reference" with "reference type." Reference types are passed by value by default, unless you use the `ref` keyword. When you pass a reference type by value, it is the same as passing anything by value; you are passing a copy. In this case, you are passing a copy of the reference.

In this example...

```
private void SetName(Book book, string name)
{
    book.Name = name;
}
```

...you are passing a reference type by value. The variable `book` is populated with a *copy* of the caller's variable `book1`. However, the variable itself contains a reference to the same `Book` object as the caller's, so setting its properties shows up in both places.

In this example...

```
private void GetBookSetName(Book book, string name)
{
    book = new Book(name);
}
```

...you are also passing a reference type by value. However, you are overwriting the (copied) value with a reference to a *new* `Book`. It's just a copy, and has no effect on `book1`.

In this example...

```
private void GetBookSetName(ref Book book, string name)
{
    book = new Book(name);
}
```

...you are passing a reference type by reference. The method receives a pointer to the original reference, which it can change. Therefore when you assign it a new `Book`, it shows up in both places.

Comment: So in the last case, since book now holds a new reference to a new object, does book1 in the calling function also now contain a reference to this new object?

Comment: Yes. When you pass by reference, the method doesn't receive a copy, it receives a reference to the original value (which is a reference to a Book object). Since it doesn't have its own copy, updating it affects the caller too.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case, book is not really being passed by reference but it IS a reference type.  We know this because `Book` is a **reference type**. re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types and not a value type.

SO, when that first example private sets the `book.Name = name;` it does that in the `book` reference for the reference type it was passed.

In the second example, you set `book` to a NEW `book` of `Book` type which creates a NEW book for the reference and then sets the `Name` of that (not a good practice since it is doing TWO things really) - and of course the original reference does not know about the NEW book, only the book it has a reference to.

Now in the third example you pass a reference type by `ref` and then change it to a new `Book` with a new name - and since it is a reference, the original `book1` picks up the new object and the name.

```
private void GetBookSetName(ref Book book, string name)
{
    book = new Book(name);
}
```

If it helps `GetBookSetName` should really be `SetBookToNewBookWithNewName` or some such for this last example.

Comment: Late in the day, I hope this helps clear up the concept in some fashion.